# AngularJs - option change to default every time load page again

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying my best to learn it, but now I have a problem. Here my code :

```
 <select
                    ng-model="myTag"
                    ng-change="filterByTag(myTag)"
                    >
                <option value="">All</option>
                <option ng-repeat="tag  in TagList" value="{{tag}}">{{tag}}</option>
</select>
```

I want to make a selected able for Tag filter and every time I choose the option it will load a page again to find the suited post. However, every time I refresh the page it doesn't remember what I have choose but it automatically move to the first choose in the optional.
So I have a question how can I make the browser to remember my choose every time it refresh

Comment: Have you tried saving it to a persistent store? i.e. DB

Comment: yeah, I have think about that but I would rather go without DB

Comment: How about window local storage?